# NoReverseMatch at /availability/1/edit/ Reverse for 'availability_list' with no arguments not found. Tried: ['availability\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/list$']

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this error using Django 3 when trying to either 1) create a new object (CreateView), or 2) edit an existing one (UpdateView). Using CBVs and ModelForms.

I explored similar questions on Stackoverflow. Very often, it's about the template missing pk reference, but I triple-checked that and it doesn't seem to be the case.

Any idea?

Here are my codes:

**URLs**

```
path('availability/<int:pk>/list', views.AvailabilityListView.as_view(), name='availability_list'),
path('availability/new/', views.AvailabilityCreateView.as_view(), name='availability_new'),
path('availability/<int:pk>/edit/', views.AvailabilityUpdateView.as_view(), name='availability_edit'),
```

**Views**

```
class AvailabilityUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'crm/availability_form.html'
    form_class = AvailabilityForm
    model = Availability

class AvailabilityUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'crm/availability_form.html'
    form_class = AvailabilityForm
    model = Availability

class AvailabilityListView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'crm/availability_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        kwargs['availabilities'] = Availability.objects.filter(staff__manager=Manager.objects.get(user=user)).filter(staff=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

**Forms**

```
class AvailabilityForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = Availability
        exclude = []
```

**Models**

```
class Availability(models.Model):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Availabilities"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('staff_list')
```

**Template**

```
{% block body_block %}
  <div class="container">
    <div class="heading">
      <h1>Availability</h1>
      <a class = 'btn btn-primary' href="{% url 'availability_new' %}">+Create new availability</a>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    {% if availabilities %}
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        {% for availability in availabilities %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{availability.pk}}</td>
          <td>{{availability.staff}}</td>
          <td>{{availability.start}}</td>
          <td>{{availability.end}}</td>
          <td>
            <a href="{% url 'availability_edit' pk=availability.pk %}">Edit</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    {% else %}
    <p class='empty'>Staff does not have any availability</p>
  {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The error in the title of your question indicates that you're somewhere trying to call `reverse` without any `pk`. Where is the `AvailabiltyList` view? Can you post it along with your other views? (Also, I don't see you using the `staff_list` view, which is on your model.)

Comment: you need to use `re_path` instead of `path`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Yes, I just updated the question with the AvailabiltyList view. I spent some time and realized that both the Update and Delete templates called the AvailabiltyList view, but did not have pk assigned to it. For some reason, I thought that the error had to do with the current template, but it had to do with Update and Delete templates. My bad.

Comment: Just to be more clear for other people in similar situation: the Update and Delete templates called the AvailabiltyList view (like so: {% url 'availability_list' %}}), but did not have pk assigned to it  (like so: {% url 'availability_list' pk=availability.pk %}}). My confusion came from the fact that generally a "list" does not require pk assignment. But here, I'm using "list" in the name of the view AvailabiltyList to refer to a specific user's availability list (which is in fact a detail view). It thus requires pk assignment.